# Using remore office local internet

Tags: networking, router, vpn, ipsec

I bought two routers (DrayTek Vigor 2866ax) to connect offices in different countries. The problem we have is we need to use internet of other country to connect to our bank accounts and local services while people are in other country. I successfully connect one PC by OpenVPN to remote router and it worked for few days and PC's IP changed to other country. However after few days it doesn't work. I think there is better solution like permanent IPSec LAN to LAN connection. My question is what is the best solution for this scenario.

Comment: "The best solution" is opinion based. // "worked for few days and PC's IP changed to other country" is not clear to understand. // Can we assume that in both countries we have "untampered" internet, free of restrictions by the state? // Do you want to connect two PCs or two local networks or do you want to integrate one PC in a remote network? Which one is the server and where starts the current job session? — *Please update your question and be much more precise to the current setup, to the expected behavior and your use-case.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
"worked for few days and PC's IP changed to other country"
I mean for few days OpenVPN could be able to connect to other side and get the DHCP IP from there and it was like PC is in the remote location on the other country. After few days it still joined the network however when I check the location of received IP by whatismyipaddress.com it shows where the PC located physically. I checked this by searching other OpenVPN users and some people had same problem.

Comment: Other thing is OpenVPN correctly connected as I could use Grandstream UCM6304A connected local lined lines. I think the default gateway somehow changed but I don't know the reason.

Comment: // Can we assume that in both countries we have "untampered" internet, free of restrictions by the state? // In both sides there are some restrictions but people set up connected networks and it works.

Comment: // Do you want to connect two PCs or two local networks or do you want to integrate one PC in a remote network? Which one is the server and where starts the current job session?

Comment: // Do you want to connect two PCs or two local networks or do you want to integrate one PC in a remote network? Which one is the server and where starts the current job session?
The best architecture for me is, in each office people can use local internet, connect to local services bank account etc. and whenever they want, can completely connect to remote office and use other country's local services bank account  etc.

Comment: Any comment and idea will be highly appreciated